# Rails - errors partial not rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm very new to Rails and full-stack development in general. I've just finished Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial 6th edition and am walking through it again to build my first project (i.e. an app that's different from the sample app built in the book, but draws on a lot of the same lessons). Catch is that new project is using Rails 7.

It was going well until I ran into issues around Chapter 7; my app will not render a partial with error messages for bad submissions to the new user form. The code in the partial executes (as verified with debugger, and later with a puts statement to output on console), but the HTML doesn't output (i.e. it cannot be found when inspecting the page in Chrome). There is a CSS issue related to newer version of bootstrap, but I even tried downgrading to the bootstrap version from the book (3.4.1) with no luck. (the offending CSS segment is commented out below)

I've banged my head on this for a few hours. Hoping it's just something dumb I'm missing. If it's a broader issue with Bootstrap vs Importmaps or something I'd also appreciate references on good places to learn these. I am extremely grateful for any ideas!

*Edit* This definitely isn't an issue with passing local variables into the partial; see code snippet and comment added at the end of this post.

**app/views/users/new.html.erb**:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Create New User') %>
<h1>Create New User</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

        <%= form_with(model: @user, local: true) do |f| %>
            <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
            
            <%= f.label :email %>* <i>required</i>
            <%= f.email_field :email %>      

            <%= f.label :first_name %>
            <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
            
            <%= f.label :last_name %>
            <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
            
            <%= f.label :phone_number %>
            <%= f.text_field :phone_number %>
            
            <% # f.label :admin, "Company Admin" %> 
            <% # f.radio_button :admin, "True" %> 
            <% # f.label :admin, "Regular User" %>
            <% # f.radio_button :admin, "False", :checked => true %> 
            
            
            <%= f.submit "Create New User", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

**app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb**:

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
  <% puts "the error partial was called" %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Example server output when submitting bad data that should generate an error (fail email validation)**:

```
 Started POST "/users" for 24.85.170.222 at 2022-02-14 01:01:56 +0000
Cannot render console from 24.85.170.222! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255, ::1
Processing by UsersController#create as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"email"=>"no123@good-email", "first_name"=>"Jeff", "last_name"=>"Lebowski", "phone_number"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create New User"}
   (0.1ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:13:in `create'
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:13:in `create'
  User Exists? (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? LIMIT ?  [["email", "no123@good-email"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:13:in `create'
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:13:in `create'
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering users/new.html.erb within layouts/application
the error partial was called
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (Duration: 1.8ms | Allocations: 701)
  Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 6.2ms | Allocations: 2949)
  Rendered layouts/_rails_default.html.erb (Duration: 6.7ms | Allocations: 6277)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (Duration: 0.5ms | Allocations: 153)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (Duration: 0.8ms | Allocations: 318)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (Duration: 0.8ms | Allocations: 258)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 18.8ms | Allocations: 11238)
Completed 200 OK in 35ms (Views: 23.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms | Allocations: 16412)
```

**Gemfile**:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "3.0.3"

gem "rails", "~> 7.0.1"   
gem "sprockets-rails"
gem "puma", "~> 5.0"
gem "importmap-rails"
gem "turbo-rails"           # Hotwire's SPA-like page accelerator [https://turbo.hotwired.dev]
gem "stimulus-rails"        # Hotwire's modest JavaScript framework [https://stimulus.hotwired.dev]
gem "jbuilder"              # Build JSON APIs with ease [https://github.com/rails/jbuilder]


gem "bootsnap", require: false
gem "sassc-rails"           # Use Sass to process CSS 

gem 'image_processing'#,           '1.9.3'
gem 'mini_magick'#,                '4.9.5'
gem 'active_storage_validations'#, '0.8.9'
gem 'bcrypt'#,                     '3.1.13'
gem 'faker'#,                      '2.11.0'
gem 'will_paginate'#,              '3.3.0'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'#,    '1.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'#,             '3.4.1'

group :development, :test do
  gem "sqlite3", "~> 1.4" 
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ] 
end

group :development do
  gem "web-console"     
  gem "rack-mini-profiler"   
  gem "spring"              
end

group :test do
  # Use system testing [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing]
  gem "capybara"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem "webdrivers"
  
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'#, '1.0.5'
  gem 'minitest'#,                 '5.11.3'
  gem 'minitest-reporters'#,       '1.3.8'
  gem 'guard'#,                    '2.16.2'
  gem 'guard-minitest'#,           '2.4.6'
end

group :production do
  gem "pg"
  gem 'aws-sdk-s3', require: false
end
```

**app/assets/stylesheets/custom.scss**:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

/* mixins, variables, etc. */

$gray-medium-light: #eaeaea;

/* universal */

body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

section {
  overflow: auto;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
  h1 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}

@mixin box_sizing {
  -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing:         border-box;
}


/* typography */

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  line-height: 1;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: $gray-light;

}

p {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}

/* header */

#logo {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: white;
  /* text-transform: uppercase; */
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
  &:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

/* footer */

footer {
  margin-top: 45px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  color: $gray-light;
  a {
    color: $gray;
    &:hover {
      color: $gray-darker;
    }
  }
  small {
    float: left;
  }
  
}


footer ul {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
}

footer ul li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

/* Forms */

input, textarea, select, .uneditable-input {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  @include box_sizing
}

input {
  height: auto !important;
}

#error_explanation {
  color: red;
  ul {
    color: red;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  }
}

/*
.field_with_errors {
  @extend .has-error;    /*this is breaking 
  /*potential solution? https://jasoncharnes.com/bootstrap-4-rails-fields-with-errors/
  .form_control {
    
    color: $state-danger-text;
  }
}
*/ 

/* Miscellaneous */

.debug_dump {
  clear:       both;
  float:       left;
  width:       100%;
  margin-top:  45px;
  @include box_sizing;
}
```

**app/controllers/users_controller.rb**:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end
  
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
  
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)   #strong params required by Rails
    #debugger
    if @user.save
      #handle succesful save
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
  
  private
  
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :admin)
    end
end
```

*Edit* Ok, I have confirmed by inserting test pieces into the code that this is something to do with HTML rendering. It is definitely not an issue with the instance variable passing into the partial (although I've now learned why that's poor practice!). Example below outputs to the command line exactly as expected, however the plaintext "False" doesn't change to "True" when erroneous data is submitted in the form. It almost seems like this is something with Ajax or similar where the form is submitted and the ruby/rails runs, but the html isn't refreshed? Furthermore - I've now written tests for the errors to appear and the tests **pass**! This is messing with my head.

**app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb**:

```
<% puts @user.errors.any? %>
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
  True
  <% puts @user.errors.count %>
  
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <% puts @user.email %>
  False 
<% end %>
```

Comment: Like the answer below, you need to pass the `@user` variable to the partial for it to trigger that conditional.  Using the answer below by dtakehta will solve the issue, although you have to change `@user` in the partial to `user`, but that solution will solve the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved! This was an issue with **Turbo / Hotwire in Rails 7** (instead of Turbolinks). In the `users_controller`, I had to change the render call to include `status: :unprocessable_entity`. The behavior works perfectly now.

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)   #strong params required by Rails
    #debugger
    if @user.save
      #handle succesful save
    else
      render 'new', status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

Thanks to all who commented. Even if using instance variables in a partial was not the issue, I did read up and learn why that's undesireable practice, so worthwhile.

I figured out the answer from this stackoverflow comment:
[Rendering a view after form submission not working correctly in Rails 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70606742/rendering-a-view-after-form-submission-not-working-correctly-in-rails-7)

Comment: Thank you! I was stuck in this error as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `app/views/users/new.html.erb`

`<%= render 'shared/error_messages', user: @user %>`

If it's a shared partial, maybe make the instance variable generic rather than  `@user` also.  That way it can be reused and less confusing later.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but no change in behaviour. I think you're correct though that the 'if' in the partial is not triggering. It confuses me because if I run debugger at the top of the partial it will tell me that @users.errors.any? evaluates to true, but then the "if" statement goes to "false".

I added a dump of my users controller in case there is something in there with the way the variable is defined.

Comment: If you do that, you'll need to rename your variable from `@user` to `user` on `shared/error_messages`.

Comment: Yep - I did that. Still didn't correct the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Use `locals` on your render:

```
render partial: 'shared/error_messages', locals: { user: @user }
```

And on `shared/error_messages` rename `@user` by `user`.

Comment: This actually throw an error: "undefined local variable or method `user' for #<ActionView::Base:0x0000000000e808> Did you mean?  @user"      

The user variable passes to the partial correctly if I do it the way proposed by dtakeshta below without using "local: {}", but still doesn't render correctly. It doesn't render if I do away with the partial completely and just drop the code straight into /user/new.html.erb, so there is something else going on...

Comment: My bad, I forgot `partial`. Can you try it? 